# Repair Teleporter in Fallout 4

Tags: pc, fallout-4

I built the teleporter in Sanctuary Hills and used it to get into the Institute. The settlement was later attacked and the teleporter was damaged. Unfortunately, because it's a unique building, it cannot be repaired.

I understand that the teleporter is necessary in the future if I want to choose the path of destroying the institute with the Minutemen, so it needs to be operational.

Is there some way to repair it? Especially convenient would be a simple console command (PC version) to repair settlement objects, which I wasn't able to find.

Comment: I don't remember needing it again for anything, even on the minuteman ending

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finished the game with each faction at least once, and I've done very nearly every side quest in the game with one character or another.

**You don't need the molecular relay again for anything ever**, it is always damaged after you use it, and I don't believe it can be repaired.

In the final Minutemen quest, you'll use the relay inside the institute, not the one you built in your settlement.

Furthermore, if you ask the tech person about testing the relay before the first time you use it, they will tell you that it is only going to work once.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, you can't repair it

Bit longer answer: The teleporter gets Auto-damaged when you use it, but since you got the chip from the institute, you can travel there at any time. 
I don't know if you need the teleporter, if you want to destroy the institute with whatever faction, but since it gets auto-damaged, I guess there will be a way to repair it, if you need it again.

EDIT: I read other posts here that indicate that you don't need the teleporter anymore, not even for the destroy the institute missions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.

Console command "CallFuntion Repair" then choose the part to repair while inside the console command. This has to be done to all 4 parts separately. Then you might have to turn the power source OFF then ON again.

But it works, I do it every playthrough because I like the light show.